# Como pegar valor da primeira linha de um arquivo Texto(txt)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Então... Como vocês podem verem, a variavel `target` define o e-mail que será enviada a mensagem.

Porem, eu não consigo adicionar o valor da primeira linha da  lista.txt dentro da variavel `target`.

A ideia de uma visão mais ampla é que o script envie os e-mails, linha por linha, ou senão ele adiciona o valor da primeira linha, e no fim do loop ele remove esse valor da lista.txt e da variavel para que possa ser adicionado um novo valor.

**Como adicionar o valor da primeira linha de um arquivo texto.txt dentro de uma variavel ?**

(e depois remover primeira linha do arquivo txt, para continuar o ciclo de envios.. até a lista acabar.  `for i in xrange(texto):` )

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import smtplib
import datetime
import random
import getpass
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

class spammer():
def __init__(self):
    self.banner()
    self.spam()

def banner(self):
    print """                                                          

    By Mandrake Venom 2018
                                                      """

arq = open('./lista.txt', 'r')
texto = len(arq.readlines()) -1
valor = "" 
print "[+] Total de Emails [+] "
print "========================="
print texto 
print "========================="
print valor
arq.close()

def spam(self):
    # Credentials
    username = raw_input("Login [gmail]: ")
    password = raw_input("Senha: ")
    target = raw_input("Enviar email para: ")
    assunto = raw_input("Assunto: ")
    men = input("Body: ")

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    try: server.login(username, password)
    except: print "[-] Authentication Error" ; exit()

    print "[!] Preparando para Enviar "

    try:
        for i in xrange(texto):             
            subj = assunto,  random.randrange(0,9999999999999)
            content = MIMEText(men, 'html')
            name = "fulano"
            date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime( "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" )             
            msg = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\nDate: %s\n\n%s" % (name, target, subj, date, content)
            server.sendmail(username, target, msg)
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
            print "[-] An Error Occured During Process | " 
            print "[!] The target email might be wrong [Error] ===> ",target 
            exit()
    server.quit()
    print "[+]", target, " [Enviado] Continue ===>"

try:
spammer()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print "\n[!] Tchau! byeee byeeeeee.... "
exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente isto:

```
with open('lista.txt', 'r') as f:
    primeira_linha = f.readline()
```

O `with` vai usar o arquivo e fechar e o `readline` vai ler a primeira linha.

Comment: File "mail-spammer.py", line 22
    print primeira_linha
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Esse erro é de como vc indentou o código, não tem nada haver com o código que postei *IndentationError*, Python exige uma "boa" indentação.

Comment: botei no começo do codigo, e mandei um `print primeira_linha` , ja tentei desse jeito e ate da outra maneira `for i in lines arquivo` da erro... a maioria das resposta do google eu ja rodei

Comment: entao, python eu sou cabaço